# Mysql json field and algolia

Tags: algolia

i want to add this table to the algolia:

`+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| data  | json             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

there is only one row on this table and content of data is:

```
[
   {
      "id":"7cc481e3eab24b4ef9ccc945c00f7784",
      "desc":"shirts desc",
      "name":"Shirts",
      "slug":"shirts",
      "image":"7cc481e3eab24b4ef9ccc945c00f7784.jpeg",
      "categories":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"67d188521fa8531dd3e2044814cb942342",
      "desc":"some desc",
      "name":"Jackets",
      "slug":"jackets",
      "image":"67d188521fa8531dd3e2044814cb942342.jpeg",
      "categories":[
         {
            "id":"671a83b87369ee6773774c0d6d4455e2",
            "desc":"sealed desc",
            "name":"Sealedq",
            "slug":"sealedq",
            "image":""
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"ad03b6be35714f7bb7f2ecc82d512c79",
      "desc":"some desc",
      "name":"Trousers",
      "slug":"trousers",
      "image":"ad03b6be35714f7bb7f2ecc82d512c79.jpg"
   },
   {
      "id":"ea265cbc18db7ad6b3a3013af3070890",
      "desc":"some desc",
      "name":"Sweaters",
      "slug":"sweaters",
      "image":"ea265cbc18db7ad6b3a3013af3070890.jpeg"
   }
]
```

these all work with Laravel 5.2,
when i send these data to algolia, it will create only one record and set objectID to id of table.
[image: Alglia]

How can i send only data field to algolia and set id of data field as objectID?

i use this code for just to test and it works for me, but i think this is not the right way, maybe i should use Synonyms.

```
$client = new AlgoliaSearch\Client("AppID", "AdminKey");
$index = $client->initIndex('catalog');


$results = Model::select('data')->first();
$results = json_decode($results->data,  true);
if ($results)
{
  $batch = array();
  // iterate over results and send them by batch of 10000 elements
  foreach ($results as $row)
  {
    // select the identifier of this row
    $row['objectID'] = $row['id'];

    array_push($batch, $row);


  }

 return $index->saveObjects($batch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i send only data field to algolia and set id of data field as objectID?
>
> i use this code for just to test and it works for me, but i think this is not the right way, maybe i should use Synonyms.

Parsing the content of the data on your side and adding it to the object is the right way to go. I don't know the PHP framework you're using but you can probably do something like:

```
$batch = array();
$rows = Model::select('*')->all();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $row['objectID'] = $row['id']
  $row['data'] = json_decode($row['data'],  true);
  array_push($batch, $row);
}
$index->saveObjects($batch);
```

Synonyms are used for something else. You can read more [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/relevance/synonyms)